# How to print value from db in python CGI

Tags: python, mysql, cgi

I am beginner and trying constantly to print value on web page through cgi-bin but i dont know what i am doing wrong. I gone through different tutorials like:

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/python/how-to-use-python-to-connect-to-a-database

http://ianhowson.com/a-quick-guide-to-using-mysql-in-python.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm
and some threads as well like: [Returning Output of Python CGI MySQL Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443209/returning-output-of-python-cgi-mysql-script) because i think i am doing wrong somewhere but fail to print.

here is my code and it only **prints** `"hello"`:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe

import cgi
import cgitb

print "Content-type: text/html\n"
print """
<html>
<head>
<p> hello</p>
</head>
"""

import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=3306, user="root", passwd="",db="project")


cursor = db.cursor()
cursor2 = db.cursor()
# execute SQL select statement
#sql = "SELECT stid,firstname FROM student WERE stid IN(SELECT stid FROM stobt WHERE stid=%s" % (0)

sql2 = "SELECT stid FROM student  WHERE firstname = '%s'" % ('User')


# Execute the SQL command

cursor2.execute(sql2)
# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.

result2 = cursor2.fetchall()
#print result2

row2 = result2[0]
#print 'r1',row[1]
#print 'r2',row2[0]
sql = "SELECT * FROM stobt  WHERE stid = '%d'" % (row2)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
row = results[1]
tc = 56
for row in results:

   if row2[0] == row[1]:
      idd = row[0]
      stid = row[1]
      obtained = row[2]
      subject = row[3]

   # Now print fetched result

      print( "<h1>id=%s,stid=%s,obtained=%f,subject=%s</h1>" %(idd, stid, obtained, subject ))

print """
<body>
<p> idd</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
    #  if obtained <= 50:
     #    if tc >= 50:
      #      print tc
db.close()
```

Any idea?

Comment: It may not be the only problem, but your HTML is completely broken. Your `h1` must be inside the `body` element, which means you need to print `<body>` *before* you do the SQL stuff. Note also that your "hello" string should also be inside the body, not the head.

Comment: i placed <body> after </head> and yet no printing of sql db values.....

Comment: So, what does the generated source look like (if you do View Source in your browser)? Does it have the right data?

Comment: <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: OK, do you actually have a user with the firstname "User" in your student table? Do you have any records with that user's id in your stobt table?

Comment: yea and even i checked by runing on python idle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105732/discussion-between-user3508182-and-daniel-roseman).